# Problems with Adobe Student Plan

Tags: adobe-illustrator

so I'm a student and I'm interested in graphics and was looking to get Adobe Illustrator. Now, Adobe Illustrator is way too costly, so I was looking at the student plan, but the student plan includes the whole Creative Cloud, but I am only interested in Adobe Illustrator, and buying separately (not part of the Creative Cloud) would cost me the same. Is there any way to get discounted student rates on Illustrator separately? Also on a side note, I tried contacting Adobe, but did not know how to do that, so it would also be helpful if someone could tell me how to contact Adobe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not programming question

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.adobe.com/tw/about-adobe/contact.html
the tw will be replaced by whatever country you are in.